# delete_term is not working properly with add_action()

Tags: functions, hooks, actions, terms

`delete_term` is not working, I'm trying to delete term and after I deleted it, it'll also delete the similar term from different a taxonomy based on their slugs

here's my code of the `delete_term`, so in the code below, when I deleted a term from `movies_category` taxonomy, it'll look/find for a similar `slug` from `category` (the default wordpress taxonomy for **Posts**), and then delete it also programmatically, but the code doesn't work on my end, I'm not sure where did I go wrong here.

```
function delete_similar_term($term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy, $deleted_term) {
    if( $deleted_term->taxonomy === 'movies_category' ) {
        $post_cat_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $deleted_term->slug, 'category' );
        wp_delete_term( $post_cat_term->term_id, 'category' );
    }
}
add_action( 'delete_term', 'delete_similar_term' , 10, 3 );
```

It's hard for me to debug this also because I can't see any errors, when I delete a term from my `movies_category` it will just highlight the term red and AJAX delete stops working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, `slug` is unique. So `$post_cat_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $deleted_term->slug, 'category' );` shouldn't return anything.

Instead, you may try `name`.

Also, `delete_term` callback gets 5 parameters, so it's better to adjust that accordingly.

See if the following works:

```php
function delete_similar_term( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy, $deleted_term, $object_ids ) {
    if( $deleted_term->taxonomy === 'movies_category' ) {
        $post_cat_term = get_term_by( 'name', $deleted_term->name, 'category' );
        wp_delete_term( $post_cat_term->term_id, 'category' );
    }
}
add_action( 'delete_term', 'delete_similar_term' , 10, 5 );
```

Comment: Yeah, that works thanks!! Just a question, so If a property is unique it can't be used `get_terms_by()`?

Comment: Ohhh I see, so the error in this is that I didn't add the $object_ids param and used `10, 3` instead of `10, 5`. I tried the `$deleted->slug` and it still works, thanks @karma, I just learned a thing today!